# FBSDK activateApp keeps prompting me to sign in to the iTunes Store?

Tags: ios9, fbsdk

I just recently added the FBSDK into my app to track when users run the app so I can hopefully put ads and pay for every app install. The following code is used to detect when a user has opened the app, but it's also the one causing a bug. This code is the culprit.

```
FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
```

Every time I start my app, it pops up the annoying "Sign into iTunes Store" alert. When I comment out that code, it doesn't happen. When the code is there, it shows the log in alert every time and it's really annoying.

I have the latest iOS, and latest FBSDK.

I've moved this piece of code to other places in my game and the log in alert shows up where that code executes. I also tried the FBSDKAppEvents.logEvent and it shows the alert a few seconds later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch this behavior off by clicking the "Log In-App Purchase Events Automatically (Recommended)" button in your app configuration panel.